# Installing a local Logstash plugin gem

Tags: ruby, logstash, amazon-kinesis

## What is the interest?

Writing a Logstash output plugin for AWS Kinesis.

## What was already achieved?

Using [this tutorial](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/_how_to_write_a_logstash_input_plugin.html), `logstash-output-sqs-0.1.3.gem` was built from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-sqs).

## What is the problem?

Installing the gem file using the `plugin install` command:

```
bin/plugin install ~/logstash-output-sqs-0.1.3.gem
```

### Logstash 1.4.2

```
Can only install contrib at this time... Exiting.
```

### Logstash 1.5.0 beta1

```
The error reported is:
  sqs must set a milestone.
```

### Logstash 1.5.0 rc2

```
Error reading plugin file ~/logstash-output-sqs-0.1.3.gem, caused by NameError
```

## What are the questions

- Which Logstash version is preferable for plugin development?
- How can this error be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work with Logstash 1.5.0 beta1 as follow:

In my class in `lib/logstash/outputs/kinesis.rb` I added:

```
milestone 1
```

In `logstash-output-kinesis.gemspec` I changed dependency from:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "logstash-core", '>= 1.4.0', '< 2.0.0'
```

to

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "logstash", '>= 1.4.0', '< 2.0.0'
```

BTW the plugin is ready:

https://github.com/adience-code/logstash-output-kinesis

[This commit](https://github.com/adience-code/logstash-output-kinesis/commit/a73a5fff7a01885abec797f8347437ed3ad5ce45) is compatible with Logstash 1.5.0 beta1.